# Docusign: disabling sender's ability to edit recipients

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using the Docusign REST APi v2 to set up docusign links for "senders" to receive links which open the docusign sender view console to place signature tags. And also to provide recipients their links to open the signing/recipient console.

We want to lock down what the senders can do as much as possible since everything the console needs will be provided to the API from our web site. We managed to go into the Docusign sandbox's preferences and munder the features menu, we disabled various tag options and custom tagging.

I have only one thing left I'd like to do; Disable the ability for the sending console to change recipient (that to/from area at the top of the console).

The users of our console only need to place the tags and hit send; we don't want them messing with the recipients themselves.

In the same features screen I disabled some features named:

- Enable Send To Address Recipients
- Enable Send To Manage Envelope
- Enable Send To Manage Recipients

It did not have the intended effect.

Is this possible to disable this area?

Comment: There appears to be some sort of setting when creating a template that when checked will state that the sender cannot edit, add, modify, delete recipients. This is exactly what I want, but I can't use templates. Every single document my application uses is going to have completely different documents uploaded to the envelope  through the API and the recipient is never going to be the same. Is there a way to create a template that's just 100% "blank: with no documents or recipients added and use that do build an envelope add a new document to that envelope??

Comment: I tried creating a template with just one document , setting it so sender cant edit recipients, and then when building the envelope, just added the ID of the template, but I got a bad request: <envelopeDefinition>
<emailSubject>DocuSign API - Signature Request on Document</emailSubject>
<status>created</status>
<templateid>A92100BD-5D3A-46DB-BB7F-4A616702A45D></templateid>
<recipients>
<signers>
<signer>
<recipientId>1</recipientId>
<clientUserId>100001</clientUserId>
<email> recipientEmail & "</email>
<name> recipientName & "</name>
</signer>
</signers>
</recipients>
</envelopeDefinition>

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem Brian?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to accomplish this using one of the additional recipient types such as the `editor` recipient.

Editors can modify tabs of an envelope and can also edit recipient information, however you can stop them from modifying the recipient name and email through additional body parameters `canEditRecipientEmails` and `canEditRecipientNames`.

[Editor Recipient](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Recipients/Editors%20Recipient.htm) type from API docs.

Comment: I added that to pretty much every single call I had... when creating the envelope, getting the sender URL, recipientURL... doesn't seem to do anything. Setting it to true, didn't enable the editing of recipients to the recipientview. Setting it to false, still made the editing of names/emails available to the sender. –

Comment: Just some examples of what didn't work (had no effect.. still can edit recipients): 
        url = baseURL + uri + "/views/sender"
        xmlBody = "<returnUrlRequest><editors><canEditRecipientEmails>false</canEditRecipientEmails><canEditRecipientNames>false</canEditRecipientNames></editors><returnUrl>" & returnUrl & "</returnUrl></returnUrlRequest>"
        myRequest = initializeRequest(url, "POST", xmlBody, username, password, integratorKey)
        myResponse = getResponseBody(myRequest)
        mystring = parseDataFromResponse(myResponse, "url")

Answer (score 0):

You can use [composite templates](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Send%20an%20Envelope%20from%20a%20Template.htm) to perform the situation you described in one of your comments: 'Is there a way to create a template that's just 100% "blank: with no documents or recipients added and use that do build an envelope add a new document to that envelope?? '

Using composite templates allows you to specify a template ID and then override the underlying PDF bytes. You can create a new template and upload a blank PDF. Make sure there are no signers and then set the option to not allow editing recipients. Then specify the recipient in your JSON when creating the envelope (by the way, this is a multipart form with the boundary set to MY_BOUNDARY):

```
--MY_BOUNDARY
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Disposition: form-data

{
   "emailSubject":"test subject",
   "emailBlurb":"test blurb",
   "compositeTemplates":[
      {
         "serverTemplates":[
            {
               "sequence":1,
               "templateId":"<blank pdf template>"
            }
         ],
         "inlineTemplates":[
            {
               "sequence":1,
               "recipients":{
                  "signers":[
                     {
                        "email":"email@domain.com",
                        "name":"first last",
                        "recipientId":"1",
                        "roleName":"Signer",
                        "clientUserId":"1"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ],
         "document":{
            "documentId":"1",
            "name":"test1.pdf"
         }
      }
   ],
   "status":"created"
}

--MY_BOUNDARY
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: file; filename="test1.pdf"; documentId="1";
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

<pdf bytes>

--MY_BOUNDARY--
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by setting below attribute at envelope level[EnvelopeDefinition.class] i.e.

```
@ApiModelProperty(example = "null", value = "When set to **true**, prevents senders from changing, correcting, or deleting the recipient information for the envelope.")
  @JsonProperty("recipientsLock")
  public String getRecipientsLock() {
    return recipientsLock;
  }
  public void setRecipientsLock(String recipientsLock) {
    this.recipientsLock = recipientsLock;
  }
```